# Doctrine - Undefined clas const JSON_ARRAY

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I got this message error: On stack trace I cant find the file that produces it. I'm using symfony 5 and doctrine.

```
Undefinied class constant 'JSON_ARRAY'
```

I search in all project for JSON_ARRAY with out results.

Stack Trace:

[image: Stack Trace - 1]
[image: Stack Trace - 2]
[image: Stack Trace - 3]
[image: Stack Trace - 4]

Comment: _"On stack trace I cant find the file that produces it."_ This doesn't make any sense -- what does the stack trace show?

Comment: I add the screen shots to question. Sry, i try to copy the stact trace but it is to long to post it

Comment: Right, so what's on DoctrineExtractor.php line 283?

Comment: I never touch that file it is a Doctrine file

Comment: It was working until yesterday. I try to figure out why it show me the error now. I was looking for chenges on my clasess by I cant find any diference. The biggest change was an update on composer.json

Comment: if you recently updated composer.json; did you update both doctrine *and* doctrine-bridge? The error is from doctrine-bridge so that package might be expecting a class constant from doctrine that doesn't exist in that version

Comment: I will check it

Comment: I checked it. What i found I dont got doctrine-bridge. It might be necesary?  My doctrine version on composer.json are:    "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.2",
"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.0"  Might I install doctrine-bridge?

Comment: I try in the other branchs I have on the proyect, where the proyect is running. I try to access the api docs route and I find failing again. I think should be a problem with my symfony versión or someething like that.

Comment: What PHP Version are you using. Did that change recently in any way. This is an underlying property of the json_decode/json_encode method i think

Comment: I'm using PHP 7.4. But the problem was when I installed a new library on symfony. They update other components, One of them was causing this problem. I solved it on bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it was an update on composer json file that produce that error. After looked for a solution I find that symfony got an update that produces that error on the new versions. My solution was going to last checkpoint I did for composer json file.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue because I was using **Symfony 5.2** and **doctrine/dbal 3**.

The thing is **Symfony 5.2** is only compatible with  **doctrine/dbal 2**.

So I set **dbal** to **v2**:

```
$ composer require doctrine/dbal:^2
$ composer install
```

Then everything worked fine

Issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/43994